# GuzzleHttp async request very slow performance

Tags: php, guzzle

I used guzzle to send 100 normal HTTP GET async requests. Each of then takes about 5s to respond（use sleep() function）. It takes 50s to fulfill all the requests.

Is that normal or it was indeed slow?

version 6.3.2

Comment: There's absolutely no way for us to know with the info you've provided.

Comment: @ceejayoz You may ask. Also you may provide your experience on similar situations.

Comment: Take a tcpdump and check if those are sent in parallel or sequentially.

Comment: @zerkms They couldn't be sequential, cause that should take more than 500s.

Comment: _"Is that normal"_ - How would we know that? We know nothing about the amount of data your sending/receiving, what server you're sending it to, what server you're sending it from, what it does on each request etc... It can basically be _any_ reason for this...

Comment: @bijiDango if you know it works exactly as you expect, what is your problem about?

Comment: @zerkms I know it works exactly as I expect because it was simple. Actually it turned out to be the problem of respond server concurrent performance

Answer (score -1):

As who brought this question, I'll leave my answer here, just to help those who may have similar problem but do not know much about servers as I am.

In my case, the low performance of requests actually comes from the respond server concurrency performance.